# Is there a way to predefine an arn for AWS lambdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using cloud formation to deploy - delete - redeploy some lambdas. But I want to maintain an arn (a constant arn for each lambda) that I can use no matter if i delete and redeploy the lambda. Is that possible?

Comment: if you keep same function name, arn will be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the name of your lambda stays the same, the `ARN` will be the same.

However, keep in mind that

> the ARNs for some resources omit the Region, the account ID, or both the Region and the account ID

Here's a general format for `ARNs`:

```
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource-id
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource-type/resource-id
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource-type:resource-id
```

More on `ARN` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html).

Comment: Can we predefine function urls  in someway? or get function urls using arn ?

Comment: Not really because Lambda automatically generates a unique URL endpoint for you. Once you create a function URL, its URL endpoint never changes.